# Retrieve CMI.Interaction.N.Student_Response Value in SCORM

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

I am currently building SCORM content. I have managed to get my SCORM API to save question response to the SCORM LMS. However, I can't find a way to get "cmi.interaction.n.student_response" value.

From what I have been reading, "student_response" is write only. So what SCORM reference should I use to retrieve my value?

I am using SCORM 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SCORM 1.2 unfortunately interactions are write only and cannot be read. If you need to retrieve these values for later you should store them in suspend data. In SCORM 2004, the interactions values are read-write.

Comment: So is there any point in using "student_response" if I can't retrieve the value? Instead, just mark that question correct/incorrect? By using "cmi.suspend_data", will I have to store all my responses in one long string?

Comment: After further investigation, I am storing the users response in both suspend_data and student_response.

Comment: The reason to us student_response is so the LMS can provide reports on how the learner answered the questions.